# Ordering events with Low Search Results and Low Events

Tags: low-search, solspace-tag, low-events

I'm using the Low Search Tag extension from Low. He kindly pointed me to it so that I can find upcoming events based on a Solspace Tag.

This is correctly pulling through the events I need using the following code;

```
{exp:low_search:results tag_name="{segment_4}" websafe_separator="-" low_events:unit="upcoming" low_events:show_passed="no"}
{title}
{/exp:low_search:results}
```

However, I need to be able to order them by the Event Start Date. It doesn't seemt o be doing this by default. I tried adding 'orderby="low_events:start"' but this didn't make any difference.

Wondering if anyone else had found a solution for this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply ordering by the Low Events channel field would do the trick, so try:

```
orderby="my_low_events_field" sort="asc"
```